# How to implement end-to-end relation extraction using LSTMs

Tags: keras

I need to implement the solution described in this article: [End-to-end relation extraction using LSTMs on Sequences and Tree Structures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00770.pdf). I'm following Fig. 1 on page 3.

I'm of course new to Keras. The sequential model is pretty straightforward. The functional api allows me to fork and join different branches, handle multiple inputs and outputs. But I'm not sure where to look for solutions to implement this one.

The most troublesome parts to me are:

- how to apply the dropout from output to the hidden layer in the sequence tagging part,
- how to obtain tree structured LSTM.

I'll be really thankful for any advice I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its relatively old, so you might have already found this.
For future reference, the implementation is here - https://github.com/tticoin/LSTM-ER
And a tensorflow implementation here - https://github.com/mkacan/entity-relation-extraction